# flutter_foreground_task causing crash in iOS devices

Tags: flutter, dart, awesome-notifications, startforegroundservice

I have one app that is using two packages one is flutter_foreground_task and one is awesome notification.Awesome Notification main task is to show the notification to the user and flutter_foreground_task main task is to implement the foreground service.All the processing tasks are done by the flutter_foreground_task. This package has some inbuild function which will be called when we start our processing or when we stop our processing , and for using those function we need to create one class and extend it from the TaskHandler class. Now when we initialize the flutter foreground package, its asks where you want to show the notification(i.e androis, ios), so need to make both parameter to true , as we want to show for both android and ios.
Now the problem is that the iOS that parameter is set to false and when I am making it true, the app is crashing.
When we start the processing, at that time flutter foreground task package start the service and send the notification to the user and when the processing is completed, at that time stop service is called and at that time no notification is send to the user from the flutter foreground package, and that is the reason we are using the awesome notification so the when the processing is completed, notification should be shown to the user.

I have tried various things like upgrading the flutter_foreground_task and awesome_notfication to latest version.